# Merge the contents from two columns in a tibble and output the result as a vector

Tags: r, vector, tibble

#### Starting point

Let's say I have the following tibble:

```
fruits.dt <- tibble(
  fruit.name = c("Apple", "Orange", "Banana"),
  fruit.typ = c(2,3,5),
  fruit.color = c("red", "orange", "yellow")
)
```

#### The result should look like this...

From this tibble I want to build the following vector:

> "Apple1","Apple2","Orange1","Orange2","Orange3","Banana1","Banana2","Banana3","Banana4", "Banana5"

Or if you like as `r-code`:

```
fruits.final <- c("Apple1","Apple2",
              "Orange1","Orange2","Orange3",
              "Banana1","Banana2","Banana3", "Banana4", "Banana5"
              )
```

#### How should the vector be composed?

**From row 1**

- Take the word in the first column *fruit.name*: `"Apple"`
- Take the number in the column *fruit.typ*: `2`
- Make as many compound words as the number in the column *fruit.typ*
  (here: `2`) and use `"Apple"` and the sequence `1:n` for compound words,
  where `n` is equal to the number from the column *fruit.typ*, `2`. Partial
  result: `"Apple1", "Apple2"`. The partial result corresponds approximately to
  the following code: `apple.vec <- paste0("Apple", 1:2)`

**From row 2**

- fruit.name: `"Orange"`
- fruit.type: `3`
- partial result: `"Orange1", "Orange2", "Orange3"` or `orange.vec <- paste0("Orange", 1:3)`

**From row 3... to nrow**

Go through all rows and form a composite vector from all "partial results".

#### Solution attempts

I have tried `dplyr::mutate()` in combination with `past0()`, `sapply` or `purr::map()`, but my knowledge is too limited for this problem.
For example:

```
library("tidyverse")    
fruits.dt %>%
      mutate(fruit.code = paste0(fruit.name, 1:fruit.type))
```

With `dplyr::pull()` you can extract the corresponding columns as vectors, but after that I don't know what to do either:

```
fruit.name.vec <- fruits.dt %>%
  pull(fruit.name)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for one chain:

```
#Code
paste0(mapply(function(x,y) paste0(x,seq(1,y,by=1),collapse = ','),
              x=fruits.dt$fruit.name,y=fruits.dt$fruit.typ,SIMPLIFY = T),
       collapse = ',')
```

Output:

```
[1] "Apple1,Apple2,Orange1,Orange2,Orange3,Banana1,Banana2,Banana3,Banana4,Banana5"
```

Or this for a vector:

```
#Code 2
v2 <- mapply(function(x,y) paste0(x,seq(1,y,by=1),collapse = ','),
       x=fruits.dt$fruit.name,y=fruits.dt$fruit.typ)
#Unlist
v3 <- unlist(lapply(v2,function(x) strsplit(x,',')),use.names = F)
```

Output:

```
v3
 [1] "Apple1"  "Apple2"  "Orange1" "Orange2" "Orange3" "Banana1" "Banana2" "Banana3" "Banana4"
[10] "Banana5"
```